# Sprichwort über lebenslanges Lernen

Tags: expression

Ich brauche ein Sprichwort, welches die Wichtigkeit des lebenslangen Lernens auf eine prägnante Art und Weise ausdrückt. Wenn es sich reimt, ist es noch besser.

Im Russischen gibt es eine Redewendung *Lebe ein Jahrhundert, lerne ein Jahrhundert* (*Век живи, век учись*). Ich suche nach etwas Ähnlichem im Deutschen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dieses Zitat habe ich zum Thema Lernen schon häufiger gehört:

> „Wer aufhört zu lernen, ist tot.“ (laut [Quelle](http://gutezitate.com/autor/b.b.-king) von B.B. King)

Außerdem gibt es das Sprichwort:

> „Man lernt nie aus“

Was soviel bedeutet wie, man hat nie zu Ende gelernt. Es gibt immer noch mehr zu lernen und es gibt immer noch etwas, dass man nicht weiß. Der Spruch wird häufig verwendet, wenn man gerade etwas Neues gelernt hat:

> A: „Wusstest du schon, dass …“
>
> B: „Nein, das wusste ich nicht, aber man lernt (ja) nie aus.“

Answer (score 7):

Einigermaßen gereimt ist dieses Sprichwort:

> Man wird so alt wie eine Kuh und lernt doch immer noch dazu.

Ob es weit verbreitet und bekannt ist, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: Ich kenne den Spruch als "Man wird so alt wie eine Kuh und lernt _doch_ immer noch dazu". Den Spruch habe ich aber das letzte Mal in der Grundschule gehört und verwendet ^^

Comment: @Iris Ja, so hört es sich besser an! Habe ergänzt :)

Comment: @Alex.S Das Sprichwort „man wird alt wie [ei]ne Kuh und lernt immer noch dazu“ findet man auch im Duden Band 11 _Redewendungen_. Es hat also sicherlich eine gewisse Verbreitung.

Answer (score 3):

Siehe:  [Wanders Sprichwörterlexikon](http://www.zeno.org/Wander-1867/A/Lernen?hl=lernen); am besten trifft es #66

> Man muss lernen, so lange man lebt.

Oder noch besser im Unterpunkt

> Im Reiche der Vernunft gibt es keinen Stillstand. Wer darin nicht vorwärts kommt, geht zurück; wer nicht täglich klüger wird, der wird täglich dümmer.

Answer (score 0):

Speziell in Bezug auf das Leben fällt mir nur "Wir lernen nicht für die Schule, sondern für das Leben" ein. 
Das ist zwar eigentlich von Seneca (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_vitae,_sed_scholae_discimus), aber dennoch sehr gebräuchlich im deutschen Sprachraum.

Comment: Meines Erachtens passt das nicht zur Frage, da diese Redewendung nicht auf lebenslanges Lernen, sondern auf den lebenslangen Nutzen schulischen Lernens bezogen ist.